# Social integration pinterest with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pinterest, laravel-5.5, socialauth

Hi I was trying to create Pinterest authentication in my Laravel project using this package :

> I am using laravel 5.5

And this is the package

> https://github.com/dirkgroenen/Pinterest-API-PHP

I am doing this in my controller as for testing :

```
 $pinterest = new Pinterest(env('PINTEREST_CLIENT_ID'), env('PINTEREST_CLIENT_SECRET'));
    $loginurl = $pinterest->auth->getLoginUrl(env('CALLBACK_URL'), array('read_public'));
    echo '<a href=' . $loginurl . '>Authorize Pinterest</a>';
```

Now these values of `client_id` , `client_secret` and `callback` are correct. I have verified them.. I get the screen where it creates an anchor tag with a link but when I click on it, it gives me this error :

```
{
 "status": "failure",
 "message": "Something went wrong on our end. Sorry about that.",
 "code": 12,
 "data": "path: /oauth/\nparams:[('state', [u'21881cf']), ('redirect_uri', 
 [u'https://bhgre-social.dev/']), ('response_type', [u'code']), 
 ('client_id', 
 [u'fae8f5c5c5e0d04c9f7a7cf42cbff1d995e6be163cdf922f7deb21a02f37fe7f']), 
 ('scope', [u'read_public']), ('client_secret', 
 [u'4926501681255951105'])]\ninvalid literal for int() with base 10: 
 'fae8f5c5c5e0d04c9f7a7cf42cbff1d995e6be163cdf922f7deb21a02f37fe7f'"
 }
```

Yes I know I can not share my `client id` and `client secret` but the reason is that I think the error shows that there is something wrong with it so..

Its a test account so no worry.

Comment: why are you not using socialite for pinterest?

Comment: socialite doesnt have pintetrest support. or does it

Comment: yeah it has check this out http://socialiteproviders.github.io/providers/pinterest/

Comment: but i have installed this package https://github.com/laravel/socialite
are they both the same ?

Comment: socialite contains all the providers whereas the link I have supplied contains only pinterest providers